# Google OpenID-OAuth hybrid implementation on Heroku

Tags: ruby, openid, oauth, heroku

I am looking for a step by step guide to implement Google OpenID+OAuth in our Webapplication running on Heroku for getting calendar/contacts data. I have looked at many documents and Q&A about this but still can't make things work and was wondering if anyone here knew of a place which describes the plugins, gems needed and a step by step guide. The reason for using the hybrid is that we need a permanent token from Google that we can track for users across multiple sessions.

Truly appreciate any help.

Best,

_KK

Comment: I do not think there is one. I can log a user user using ominauth and openid but then I do not now how to get the the user's contacts. I have PortableContacts with need an oauth token, but I am missing how, with openid I can get a oauth token.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Google's OpenID to access other service. So you will need to ask user to provide username/password when you want to access calendar (make sure it's SSL-ed!).

So for calendar you can use: [GCal4Ruby](http://cookingandcoding.com/docs/gcal4ruby/).

But in general you can access user data using official [Google GData gem](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/gdata_on_rails.html#Introduction).